# I can't send a JSON from a TCP client hosted on the PIC32MZ microcontroller

Tags: c, json, http, tcp

I'm working with the PIC32MZ2048EFM100, with Harmony 3 and XC32 v 4.00.

I've gotten Harmony 3's example called tcpip_tcp_client to work correctly on my hardware.

I'm now modifying the project to send a query of type POST.

The original code that tries to communicate with a remote http server is like this and it works without problems:

```
sprintf(buffer, "GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\n" "Host: %s\r\n" "Connection: close\r\n\r\n", appethData.path ? appethData.path : "null" ,appethData.host);
```

And I have modified it as follows:

```
sprintf(buffer, "POST /%s HTTP/1.1\r\n" 
"Host: %s\r\n"
"Connection: close\r\n\r\n"
"Content-type: application/json\r\n"
"Content-length: %d\r\n\r\n"
"%s", appethData.path ? appethData.path : "null" ,appethData.host,strlen(My_JSON),My_JSON);
```

But the server tells me the following:
[image]

As I understand this problem (411) happens when Content-Length is not used,

But is not the case. If I print buffer I get this, where you can see that Content-length has a value of 69

"buffer is ...

=====================

```
POST /EXO.Service/DPDV/Ok HTTP/1.1
Host: 84.105.111.79
Connection: close

Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 69

{"Type":1,"Uid":"123456789","Port":6777,"ConnectionType":0}
```

====================="

I'm not a networking expert, so I have no idea what I can do.

Any suggestion or comment is welcome

Comment: Content length `69` a typo ? coz data provided is only `59` octets length.  Try `"Connection: close\r\n\r\n"` to `"Connection: close\r\n"`

Comment: Two pairs of `CRLF` separates the header from body.

Comment: @Sparkot you're right, it worked by removing the extra \n\r